# Why aren't my roses and fruit trees blooming as much as they did last year?

Tags: soil, pruning, roses, blossom-end-rot

I just don't get it - I have a number of roses and it is June in the UK now. Granted, it has not rained much nor been overly sunny but I can't get my head around the fact that hardly anything in my garden has blossomed?!

I have had the great number of 1...yes, ONE rose that has come through and that's it. Normally, as in the last few years, I have had 50 times that much by now. Even my plum tree (albeit about 3 years old and small) has only got 2 plums that are growing - I remember last year (when it was smaller) it had loads more - about 10-15.

I have not watered much as I did last year so that could be it but it has not been dry so I would have thought something would have come through  -really disappointed.

I did prune a bit last year in about September/October to hope that this year I would have had more then last year - but the opposite has happened.

Also, the roses that did blossom last year do not have any of those fat things that a rose comes out from (not sure what they are called) - its like all the roses as doing is just growing leaves!

Makes it worse when I see other people's gardens that clearly are not taken care of having more roses and blossomed then mine!

Comment: Do you know how to prune or did you just gave a go with the secateurs? I'm asking not to criticize, simply to get an idea of your gardening experience. And is this just about the roses? Maybe you should move the plum to another question - just a thought.

Comment: Did you fertilize them this year, or give them any soil amendments?

Answer (score 2):

You say you're in the UK - I don't know where you are in the UK, but even in the south here, its been unusually cool, windy and we've even had a couple of light frosts overnight this week, which isn't normal at all. Gardens I go to where I usually do a hard cut back of certain shrubs after flowering at the end of May were in a similar condition - I couldn't cut back because flowering hadn't happened yet, although the buds were present. We have had sun, but the air temperature is still low, more as it is in April than June, and that may well account for some of the problems you're seeing, in particular with your plum tree, its possible the blossom was caught by late frost. Otherwise, although there has been some rain, windy weather does dry things out a lot faster.

As for the roses, the word you're grasping for presumably is 'bud' when you mention 'fat things'... roses aren't too bad at coping with cool temperatures, but if you're towards the north, then perhaps its just been a bit too cool. It might be useful if you could add some photos to your question, particularly of the roses you're concerned about.